# How to send email with pdf attachment in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this application that I have built on CodeIgniter 4.
Essentially, when a person registers, it is supposed to send an email with a pdf attachment. Now I have created the form and the system is generating the pdf very well.

However, it is not attaching the said pdf and the details which are predefined.

I am using Codeigniter 4 and it is really squeezing the juices out of my brains.

Here is my controller. I have pasted it in the pastebin.com

I will really appreciate help in figuring out where I am going wrong

https://pastebin.com/8Rdn7yrd

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
                        class Sender{
                            
                        public function sendEmail($mail){
                            
                            // phpinfo();
                           $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";
                           $email = \Config\Services::email();
                           $email->setFrom('myemail@example.com', 'My Subject Here');
                           $email->setTo('myemail@example.com');
                           $email->setSubject('My Subject Here');
                           $email->setMessage($message);//your message here
                           // Attachment file
                           
                               $file = $mail['file'];
                               if(!empty($file) > 0){
                                
                                $path = 'path/to/apps/';
                                
                                $filename = $path.$file;
                                 
                                if(file_exists($filename))
                                {
                                   $realfile = 'path/to/apps/'.$filename;
                                  $email->attach($filename);
                                 
                                } else{
                                    echo 'Email successfully sent';
                                }
                                
                            }

                               
                               if ($email->send()) 
                                    {
                                        echo 'Email successfully sent';
                                    } 
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        $data = $email->printDebugger(['headers']);
                                        print_r($data);
                                    }
                               exit;




                        // Email body content
                        $htmlContent = '
                            <html>
                        <body>

                          <div>
                          <img src="example.com/path/to/images/logo.jpg" alt="africa_header"/>
                          </div>
                         <p>My content goes  here</p>
                          </div>

                        <div>
                        <img src="example.com/path/to/images/header.png"/>
                        </div>
                        </body>

                        </html>
                        ';



                        // Preparing attachment

                        if(!empty($file) > 0){
                            
                            $path = 'path/to/apps/';
                            
                            $filename = $path.$file;
                             
                            if(file_exists($filename))
                            {
                               $realfile = 'example.com/path/to/images/apps/.$filename';//.$filename;
                                
                                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                                $fp =    @fopen($realfile,"r");
                                $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($realfile));

                                @fclose($fp);
                                $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                                $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($realfile)."\"\n" .
                                "Content-Description: ".basename($realfile)."\n" .
                                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($realfile)."\"; size='64.8kb';\n" .
                                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                            } else{
                                print_r('nothing found');
                            }
                        }
                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                        $returnpath = "-f" . $from;

                        // Send email


                        echo "<pre>"; print_r($message); echo "</pre>"; 
                        $mailSent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);

                        // Email sending status
                        return $mailSent;

                        }
                        }
                        ?>
```

This is a snippet of my code but the whole code is in pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, You need to set_newline property exact like this.
Make sure you generate PDF and store it first before attaching it to email

I first create PDF and store it in my folder then

```
$config = array('protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => SMTP_HOST,
                'smtp_port' => SMPT_PORT,
                'smtp_user' => SMPT_USER,
                'smtp_pass' => SMPT_PASSWORD,
                'mailtype'  => 'html',
                'charset'   => 'utf-8'
                );
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('b@b.com', "Test User");
$this->email->to('a@a.com');
$this->email->subject("Subject");
$this->email->message('Message');
$this->email->attach('Order-000.pdf'); //Your path to pdf

if (!$this->email->send()) {
    $this->email->print_debugger(); //Will Display Errors
    return $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_status_header(200)
            ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Failed to send email'
            )));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @pranav shinde. But seems like the answer you have given me its for CI3. I am however using CI4. Please note that the app is sending the mails as it is in my code apart from attaching the invoice, which is being created automatically(and successfully) via a different controller called Profoma.php. All  need is my controller to pick up the generated pdf, which comes with a name application_new_user.pdf. Essentially, each user gets his/her own invoice generated on "Submit". Kindly help.

Comment: Okay, I cant help you directly because, I will require full code. To find the issue, do one thing see if you can open the pdf file using Codeigniter. Create another function and open that pdf file, check if there are any erros

Comment: Print the full path of the file. I doubt this code `$filename = $path.$file;`. Is it giving filepath/filename.pdf? I think .pdf is missing, do check it